# Dot notation for list of object in class

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a "fixed list" in a class, I know all the objects that are in that list and I can refer to the objects through the names. The list is immutable, except for the parameters of every object contained in this list.

Something like this

```
class Object {
   String name; // Know prior to  build time
   String color; // Can change

   Object(this.name, this.color);
}

class MyClass {
   List<Object> myList = [Object('apple', 'red'), 
                          Object('banana', 'yellow'), 
                          Object('mango', 'orange')];
}
```

I would like to access the members of the list like

```
final test = MyClass();
test.myList.apple.color = 'green'
```

Is there some "special list" that consent this type of access?
I tried using ENUM but they are not suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Map<String, String>` would be better suited for what you are trying to do.

```
final colors = HashMap<String, String>();

colors['apple'] = 'green';
```